# missing ) after formal parameters... Cant find Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, salesforce

Hi I have the following code and as soon as i try to run i get the error:

missing ) after formal parameters.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')}
var selectedRecords = {GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.   Service_Order_Activity__cLineItem  )};
sforce.connection.deleteIds(selectedRecords);
navigateToUrl(window.location.href);
```

Can somebody help me please? I dindt find the answer in all the "searche m,entioned threads"

Thank you & best regards
W.H.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of spaces between `$ObjectType.` and  `Service_Order_Activity__cLineItem`

try to change this

```
var selectedRecords = {GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.   Service_Order_Activity__cLineItem  )};
```

to

```
var selectedRecords = {GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Service_Order_Activity__cLineItem)};
```

Comment: Thank you its working now.

but if i select records by checkbox it not deleting them some how.